# No me abre Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse

Tengo el problema de que no me funciona Eclipse Luna. ¿Es posible hacer que abra bien el programa?

Dejo el log, **Data\workspace\.metadata\.log**

```
!SESSION 2016-12-24 06:42:06.460 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20120608-1400
java.version=1.8.0_111
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.event 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:08.635
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.event
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.100.v20140115-1647 [279]
]
Component2: Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.event
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.event.EventComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = 
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.osgi.service.event.EventAdmin]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.2.200.v20120522-2049 [90]
]  

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.di 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:08.807
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
    name = org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.events
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = {dependency.injection.annotation=org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.UIEventTopic}
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.e4.core.di.suppliers.ExtendedObjectSupplier]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.e4.ui.di_1.0.0.v20140328-2112 [263]
]
Component2: Component[
    name = org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.events
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.di.UIEventObjectSupplier
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = {dependency.injection.annotation=org.eclipse.e4.ui.di.UIEventTopic}
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.e4.core.di.suppliers.ExtendedObjectSupplier]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.e4.ui.di_0.10.1.v20120523-1955 [63]
]  

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:08.807
!MESSAGE [SCR] Found components with duplicated names! Details: 
Component1 : Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = {p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.1.0.v20140408-1354 [286]
]
Component2: Component[
    name = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf
    activate = activate
    deactivate = deactivate
    modified = 
    configuration-policy = optional
    factory = null
    autoenable = true
    immediate = false
    implementation = org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.transport.ecf.ECFTransportComponent
    state = Unsatisfied
    properties = {p2.agent.servicename=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.repository.Transport}
    serviceFactory = false
    serviceInterface = [org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.spi.IAgentServiceFactory]
    references = null
    located in bundle = org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf_1.0.100.v20120305-0333 [121]
]  

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2016-12-24 06:42:13.051
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.CommandServiceAddon' from bundle '54'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandServiceAddon#init()": no actual value was found for the argument "IEclipseContext".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.processAnnotated(InjectorImpl.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2016-12-24 06:42:13.678
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.addons.CommandProcessingAddon' from bundle '67'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "CommandProcessingAddon.commandService": no actual value was found for the argument "ECommandService".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2016-12-24 06:42:13.865
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.swt.util.BindingProcessingAddon' from bundle '70'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: Unable to process "BindingProcessingAddon.commandService": no actual value was found for the argument "ECommandService".
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.reportUnresolvedArgument(InjectorImpl.java:416)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.resolveRequestorArgs(InjectorImpl.java:407)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.inject(InjectorImpl.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.internalMake(InjectorImpl.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.make(InjectorImpl.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.make(ContextInjectionFactory.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.createFromBundle(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.doCreate(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:71)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.ReflectionContributionFactory.create(ReflectionContributionFactory.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.379
!MESSAGE One or more bundles are not resolved because the following root constraints are not resolved:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.379
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.annotation_2.0.0.v20140415-1436.jar was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.annotation 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.379
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.379
!MESSAGE Bundle reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.100.v20120521-2346/ was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.379
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.403
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.403
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry_3.5.100.v20120521-2346 [49] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.core.runtime.compatibility.registry 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.403
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(|(&(osgi.ee=CDC/Foundation)(version=1.0))(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.3)))".
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.403
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.ssl_1.0.0.v20120608-0148 [78] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.403
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ecf.ssl_1.0.100.v20120608-0148 [79] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.403
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.ui.win32_3.2.300.v20120523-1955 [221] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.403
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.annotation_2.0.0.v20140415-1436 [290] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.annotation 2 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.403
!MESSAGE Missing required capability Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))".

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2016-12-24 06:42:14.407
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.processHierarchy(E4Workbench.java:172)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.init(E4Workbench.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.<init>(E4Workbench.java:69)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.E4Application.createE4Workbench(E4Application.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:554)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: intentaste instalar otra version de eclipse? desinstalaste e instalaste nuevamente? En otros foros esas son parte de las soluciones que ofrecen

Comment: @sioesi Funcionó, gracias.

Comment: que hiciste al final??

Comment: @sioesi Lo desinstalé y lo volví a instalar, como habías dicho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La reinstalación soluciona el problema.

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561444/opening-eclipse-throws-an-error

Comment: eso mismo iba a dejar xD

Comment: @sioesi Jeje, lo vi antes de que lo borres, y lo puse.

Answer (score 0):

Hay una alternativa que me ha funciona con diferentes versiones de eclipse y quizá puede servir a alguien antes de reinstalar eclipse y perder sus configuraciones.

Por algún motivo que desconozco, la carpeta del jdk (java_home) se corrompe. Solo elimina esa carpeta y **vuelve a instalar el jdk** (o a copiarla nuevamente, si habías hecho un backup de esta).

Esta alternativa me ha funcionado ya en 3 ocasiones diferentes :)